# Заливка окружности цветом

Tags: c#

Как залить окружность тем цветом, который нужен именно мне? 
Есть форма, в которой пользователь выбирает цвет, и нужно этим цветом закрасить круг. В гугле написано только про то, как использовать Brushes.цвет,но мне нужно именно самому этот цвет задать

```
graph.FillEllipse(????, x, y, heigth, width);
```

Comment: У вас, полагаю  WinForms ?

Comment: `var brush = new SolidBrush(myColor)` Не забудьте вызвать `Dispose` (или обернуть в `using`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот примерно так :

```
public static Color SelectedColor { get; set; }

// Вызов диалога с выбором цвета
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ColorDialog dialog = new ColorDialog();
   dialog.ShowDialog();
   SelectedColor = dialog.Color;
}

// При нажатии ЛКМ на холст(`pictureBox`) на котором нужно нарисовать 
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(SelectedColor);
        g.FillEllipse(brush, x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```